# (telebot) как заставить бота реагировать на фото,которое он же и отправил

Tags: python, telebot

допутим у меня есть папка с 3 фото (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg) я зделал так чтобы эти файлы, при вводе определённой команды выпадали рандомно,я ввожу комманду и мне бот выдаёт к примеру 2.jpg, как зделать так чтобы бот реагировал на именно это фото(2.jpg),а на другие фото(1.jpg, 3.jpg) не реагоровал?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Никак, бот не способен реагировать на свои же сообщения. Разве что при рандомном выборе делать условие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При отправке сообщения, в случае успешной отправки возвращается само сообщение типа `Message`. Просматриваешь информацию из `photo` и уже обрабатываешь.
Как пример:

```
a = bot.send_message(id,str(randomnum))

if a.text == '1':
   print('You are good!')
```

Более подробная информация(telebot полностью имитирует API): https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage